# Paginação ajax/php nao esta funcionando em iOs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ios

A paginação do meu site está funcionando em tudo,navegadores do pc e do android, mas em iphone ou no ipad, nao esta funcionando.
Tem alguma solução que eu devo fazer para melhorar isso tudo em iOS? 
Estou usando ajax com php.
Meu script é simples:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  load_data();  
  function load_data(page)  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"pagination",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{page:page},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#pagination_data').html(data);  
            }  
       })  
  }  
  $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
       var page = $(this).attr("id");  
       load_data(page);  
  });  
});
```

Comment: Veja no Debug se há algum erro: http://html5-mobile.de/blog/ios6-remote-debugging-web-inspector

Comment: Provavelmente tu terá que usar a promisse do .done(), em vez da função success. Tenta isso:
$.ajax({  
            url:"pagination",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{page:page}
       }) .done(function(data){  
                 $('#pagination_data').html(data);  
       })